# Pasar datos de ajax a metodo de un objeto

Tags: php, ajax

Saludos de nuevo por aquí. Hace tiempo he hecho una pregunta como esta, pero esa vez solucione con una respuesta que me dieron y pues salí del paso con eso. Pero esta vez si me es necesario buscar la manera de realizar esto. Necesito procesar un formulario de registro con Ajax y pasarle los datos a mi php. Estoy usando clases, métodos, POO en fin utilizando PDO. Lo cierto es que ahora si tengo que buscar la forma de que a través de mi ajax, pasarle los datos a un método de mi clase. Es un formulario de registro y quiero pasarle los datos directamente al método de mi clase desde la variable url de mi ajax. Esto es lo que tengo hecho:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url:'Controllers/procesar_registro.php',//AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO PASARLE LOS DATOS AL METODO
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#enviar').val('Registrandote...');
    $('#enviar').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
})

.done(function(response){
  console.log(response);
    if(response.respuesta == false){
          $('#enviar').val('Registrar');
      $('#enviar').removeAttr("disabled");  
      $('#alerta_err').slideDown('slow');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#alerta_err').slideUp('slow');
      },6000);
    }else{
      $('#alerta_ok').slideDown('slow');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#alerta_ok').slideUp('slow');
        location.href = 'index.php';
      },4000);  
    }
});
});
```

PHP

```
public function NuevoAdmin(){
        if(isset($_POST['newAdmin']) && !empty($_POST)){
            $name = $_POST['name']; $ape = $_POST['ape']; $ced = $_POST['ced'];
            $id_estado = $_POST['estado']; $id_perfil = $_POST['id_perfil']; $username = $_POST['username']; 
            $pass = $_POST['pass']; $date = date('d-m-Y');

            $obj->InsertAdmin($name,$ape,$ced,$username,$pass,$date,$id_perfil,$id_estado);
        }else{

        }
     }
```

Entonces lo que quisiera es algo como esto en mi ajax

url:'Controllers/Controllers.php/NuevoAdmin', que seria el nombre de la carpeta, el del archivo y el nombre del metodo.

No tengo claro si esto se pueda hacer, pero he investigado y he visto en internet que una persona lo ha hecho de la forma en que digo pero ha usado una constante  echo URL/Nombre del metodo, y le ha funcionado. Lo he intentado y no he podido lograr que funcione, no se si es porque la forma que vi estaban usando un autoload o algo asi.

Tambien he conseguido esto:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 //cuando hagamos submit al formulario con id id_del_formulario
 //se procesara este script javascript
  $("#id_del_formulario").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"),//action del formulario, ej:
   //http://localhost/mi_proyecto/mi_controlador/mi_funcion
   type: $(this).attr("method"),//el método post o get del formulario
   data: $(this).serialize(),//obtenemos todos los datos del formulario
   error: function(){
   //si hay un error mostramos un mensaje
   },
   success:function(data){
    //hacemos algo cuando finalice todo correctamente
   }
  });
 });
});
```

En este ejemplo en la url pasa el action del formulario, entonces me daria a entender que mi formulario lo podria mandar a mi controlador?

La verdad quisiera conseguir la manera de hacerlo, sin antes tener que enviar los datos a un archivo y luego enviarlos a mi método de la clase. Quien pueda ayudarme con esto, agradecido estare!

Comment: ¿Has mirado en el sitio? Hace unas semanas se hizo una pregunta similar a esta y le dieron varias respuestas. La busco y te pongo un enlace, pero busca por aquí.

Comment: He buscado Alvaro, de hecho yo he hecho una similar a esta, pero no obtuve la respuesta que queria en si, si puedes facilitarme el link seria estupendo

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de que es tu propia pregunta (me acordaba de ella porque dejé un comentario y A. Cedano te dio una solución)... En cuyo caso, si es la misma pregunta, deberías plantearte editar la original y cerrar esta, o poner una recompensa o algo.